# Some derived classes with pre-defined values whilst others not

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, kotlin

In my Kotlin application, I deal with some membership types. For example:

```
interface MembershipType {
    fun getExcessOptions(): List 
}
```

The derived types are `GOLD`, `SILVER`, `BRONZE`, `PLATNIUM`

All 4 types have list of excess options. For example:

```
enum class MembershipType(val name: String) : IValueOptions {
    SILVER("silver") {
        override fun getExcessOptions() = listOf(300,200,100)
    }, //for GOLD, BRONZE, PLATNIUM etc
```

For `GOLD` and `SILVER` types, they can be selected as a `Bundle` and so they must have list of pre-defined `valueOptions` which one can pick from.

For `BRONZE`, `PLATNIUM`, they can only be `Named`, so user inputs their own value, they have a choice..

Basically I want to represent the following:

```
MemeberShip Type || Options           || Value Options
GOLD             || Bundle            || 100, 200, 3000
SILVER           || Bundle and Named  || 4000, 5000
PLATINUM         || Named
BRONZE           || Named


data class Bundle (
        val excess: Int
        val value: Int
) 

data class Named (
        val excess: Int
        val value: Int
) 

data class Selection(val bundle : Bundle?, val items : List<Named>)
```

How can I represent this in terms of classes and inheritence in Kotlin or even as enums as two of the types are unique in the sense they have pre-defined `valueOptions` property?

Comment: so should eg: GOLD allow obbjects of type Budle that have the listed values and nothing else ?
maybe its just me but its hard to follow what you actually want to achieve / model
this looks like it could be a good usecase for sealed classes

Comment: @Nikky - instead of "GOLD allow objects of type Bundle", it should read "You can select a Bundle of type GOLD or SILVER"

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can give you a starting point

```
sealed class MembershipType(val label: String) {
    abstract val excessOptions: List<Int>
    object GOLD: MembershipType("GOLD"), OtherInterface {
        override val excessOptions= listOf(100, 200, 3000)
        override val foo = "bar"
    }
    object SILVER: MembershipType("SILVER"), OtherInterface {
        override val excessOptions= listOf(4000, 5000)
        override val foo = "baz"
    }
}

interface OtherInterface {
    val foo: String
}
```

sealed classes are like classes and enums combined,
you cannot extend the sealed class from outside anymore and each object can extend different interfaces

more about that can be found on the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html

Comment: I was thinking `sealed classes` too and so far have what your answer shows. I am just struggling with the relationship between `Bundle` and the `MembershipTypes`. Basically, I allow user to select Bundle which is of Type GOLD or SILVER, only these two. Should `OtherInterface` be something like `BundleOption` and have type `GOLD` and `SILVER` implement it? when I construct `Bundle`, I am looking to populate one of the `excess` and one of the `values`

Comment: Construct the `Selection` class

Comment: `MembershipType` in your case could be generic to support different options types. But there is still problem with `SIlVER` that should contain 2 types.

Comment: `SILVER` can implement the other type interface ?

Comment: sure it can implement multiple interfaces and compose that parts that it needs